# NP on android.app.ActionBar.setCustomView(int) when using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have imported my eclipse project to Android studio everything is working fine. I have custom Actionbar

which is like this: Oncreate of an activity I have the following

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
 getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.bartitle);
 TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleEDIT);
 textViewTitle.setText(res.getString(R.string.title));
 setContentView(R.layout.register);
```

and now I have added Style for v21 too.

Style.xml for version 21 has the following:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

When I run the project: I get a white Screen and force Close with the following error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.flm.sPar/com.flm.sPar.Register}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setCustomView(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setCustomView(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.flm.sPar.Register.onCreate(Register.java:71)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I have been trying to solve this issue. Trying out all solutions given on SO or Google but couldn't get to solve the issue. Hence thought of asking a question on SO.

Thanks!

Comment: try `getSuppotActionBar()` With `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: @MD Not able to use getSupportActionBar()... says can't resolve the method?

Comment: @MD ActionBarActivity is deprecated in revision 22.1.0 of the Support Library and so AppCompatActivity should be used instead of ActionBarActivity.

Comment: @AlokNair OOhhhhh thanx. I don't know about that.

Comment: @AlokNair: Yes. changed it to AppCompatActivity but now I am not able to use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar() because you are using AppCompat library. If you're using the v7 appcompat library, your activity should instead extend AppCompatActivity and not Activity.

ActionBarActivity is deprecated in revision 22.1.0 of the Support Library and so AppCompatActivity should be used instead of ActionBarActivity as suggested by a user in comments.

Hope this will solve your issue :)

Comment: Yes. changed it to AppCompatActivity but now I am not able to use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

Comment: What do you mean by not able to use?

Comment: Great.. Got it working. How do I apply the same on Fragment and FragmentActivity?

Comment: You can do the same on FragmentActivity. ActionBarActivity and AppCompatActivity extends from FragmentActivity, so you can call getSupportActionBar there.

Comment: Also FragmentActivity is deprecated, so avoid using deprecated stuff. Insted use AppCompatActivity class, which is a subclass of FragmentActivity, and so allows you to use Fragment APIs on API level 7 and higher

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, how do I apply the same on Fragment? I am getting force close on fragment?  at this place ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar(); actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions() | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

Comment: Inside onActivityCreated() use this ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar(); Cast your getActivity() to ActionBarActivity if you have used ActionBarActivity instead of AppCompatActivity

Comment: Do not call getActionBar() anywhere as you are using Appcompat in your application, call getSupportActionBar() instead.